# Reverse string and first need to be reverse and 2nd need to be print as it is

Tags: java, string

this question was recently asked in interview can any one tell me the solution since i could not able to debug it

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
i could not able to do it
}

input:  hello bro how are you  
output: uoy are woh bro olleh

input: fire exit  
output: tixe fire
```

first whole string need to be reversed and then consequence string need to be reverse

Comment: As you can see in the answers, you probably need to phrase more clearly. I think what you want to ask is "How to reverse the word order in a string and every other word?" The body of your question you could probably improve by using some punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward approach is to split the input string on space, then iterate backwards, reversing every other individual word, beginning by reversing the first word.

```
String input = "hello bro how are you";
String[] parts = input.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i=0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder(parts[parts.length - i - 1]);
    if (i > 0) sb.append(" ");
    sb.append(i % 2 == 0 ? rev.reverse() : rev);
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());

uoy are woh bro olleh
```

### Demo

Comment: What is the output? Does this reverse every other word? I think that is what OP needs.

Comment: @Tim in the above program whole String is reversed

Comment: @Shiva The word _positions_ are reversed, but not every individual word is reversed.  Maybe you misunderstood the above comments.

Comment: Fine? `fire exit` yields `exit erif` instead of the desired `tixe fire`.

Comment: @Armali You're right.  I fixed that problem by changing the way I phrased the loop over words.

Answer (score 1):

Devide the problem:

1. Create array from the string by split the string by " ".
2. Reverse the array.
3. Iterate on the reversed array and reverse every 2nd element in the array.
4. Print the array.